# node.js - first request returns blank, second request returns data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm setting up a node.js api using express, body-parser and mysql.

Whenever I make a get request to a route for the first time, I get a blank return. If I fire it a second time, I get the desired return.

Here is the basic setup...

server.js

```
var express    = require('express');       
var app        = express();                
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// include the model
var Tasks = require('./models/tasks.js');


// configure api to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        

var router = express.Router();           

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {


    // do logging
    //console.log(req)
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

router.route('/tasks')

// on routes that end in /tasks/:task_id
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/tasks/:task_id')

    // get the task by id (accessed as GET)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Tasks.setProjectId(req.params.task_id);
        Tasks.setResult(req.params.task_id);

        var tasks = Tasks.getTasksByProjectId();

        res.json(tasks);

    });


app.use('/v1', router);

// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

and here is tasks.js

```
// include the db
require('../db.js');

var project_id, result;

module.exports.setProjectId = function(pid) {
    project_id = pid;
}

module.exports.setResult = function(pid) {
    //connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE project_id = ' + pid, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        result = rows;
    });
    //connection.end();
}

module.exports.getTasksByProjectId = function(){
    return result;
}
```

any ideas why the blank return on the first request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Async, async, async.

You're trying to set a module global based on an asynchronous operation which completes some indeterminate time in the future.

But, before that async operation has completed, you're trying to read the result.  So, the module global is still empty.

By the time you make the second request, the first one has actually completed to you get to see that first result.

This whole model you're using will simply not work.  You can't make asynchronous requests, but try to use them synchronously.  It simply won't work that way.

The results of all async operations can ONLY be used reliably in a callback that is called when the async operation completes.  No stuffing of results into globals because you have ZERO idea of when the operation is done and it is safe to read the global.

`.setResult()` needs to take a callback function that you can call when the result is ready and you can pass the result to the callback.  That's where you get the result.  You don't stuff it into a module global.

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable

```
var result
```

is trying to hold the value from the mysql statement that gets executed. Yet you will have to remember that all the code in Node is async. The code that is written is trying to mimic like async but is not async out-of-box. To put this in simple words, you have done code separation / refactored code and nothing much. Instead of doing this, make your code

```
setResult
```

wait for the async to accept the return value. Give it a callback parameter. Happy coding!